# Do Something When MYSQL Column Value Increments by 100

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I need to alert members of a site when their post count has reached a multiple of 100. Is it possible to run a function or echo something when a value in a mysql table reaches 100, 200, 300, etc?

Table structure:

```
username | password | email | posts
```

I'm currently displaying their post count with:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `posts` FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo "<br /><h4>Your posts:</h4>" . " " . $row['posts'];
```

**RESOLVED**: I went with Marc's suggestion of using modulo, which suited my needs.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `posts` AS posts FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$post = $row['posts'];

    if($post % 100 == 0) {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` (name, message, message_raw) VALUES ('System', '$name has reached $post posts!', '$name has reached $post posts!')");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [modulo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

> Modulo operation. Returns the remainder of N divided by M.

Like this

```
SELECT username
FROM `user` 
WHERE username='$username' AND MOD(posts,100) = 0
```

And you can check the condition every time a user do a new post

Comment: Adding an extra query on every insert usually not a good idea.

Comment: Better than a trigger and if you find the user by ID and you have an index it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: This logic does not belong in query.

Comment: If you want the list of all users with this condition, it's going to be way faster in SQL and more easy to maintain and you don't have to get ALL users from the database and do a loop with a if

Comment: I do not think it is a use case. Why would you care about all the users with 100, 200, 300 posts?

Comment: Well, there's no problem with this. Instead of getting the number of posts of a user and then do php code. you could only do this query.

Comment: @Marc - thanks mate, your suggestion to use modulo worked. I've edited my OP with the method I used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

or

Just create a cron job

Comment: This logic does not belong in MySQL. It should be done in PHP. Posts is part of user table, so when you create or try to display model you can check amount of posts.

Comment: It is possible to miss a trigger in the application if two events happen at nearly the same time and it increments from 199 to 201, so special handling is required. A MySQL trigger is guaranteed to work.